# How add new SSL connection Spring Boot jks cacerts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, jks

I have a Spring Boot application. I have a truststore cacerts file for SSL connections. I load it into the application with the command:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="$basedir/cacerts"
```

Now I need to add a new ssl connection, I have a key.jks file. How can I add it to my application?

I thought I need to add key.jks to the cacerts file, but when adding it with keytool I get exception

```
Input non a x.509 certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure your spring boot project using application properties like that :

```
# The format used for the keystore. It could be set to JKS in case it is a JKS file
server.ssl.key-store-type=
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:cacerts
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=
```